# При работе с XMLReader на php, корректно отдает только первый узел

Tags: php, массивы, xml, xmlparser

Добрый день!

При работе с XMLReader на php, корректно отдает только первый узел. Т.е. 2, 3 и т.д. почему-то не отрабатывают.
Пример xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<realty-feed>
    <generation-date>2018-03-15T13:05:52+03:00</generation-date>

    <offer internal-id="1400455">
        <type>аренда</type>
        <property-type>коммерческая</property-type>
        <category>коммерческая</category>
        <!-- и т.д. -->
    </offer>
    <offer internal-id="1400456">
        <type>аренда</type>
        <property-type>коммерческая</property-type>
        <category>коммерческая</category>
        <!-- и т.д. -->
    </offer>
```

на php написал такой набросок:

```
$xml = new XMLReader();
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$xml->open( $file );
while( $xml->read() ) {
    if( 'offer' === $xml->name ) {
        $node = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($xml->expand(), true));
        $array = json_decode(json_encode((array)$node), true);
        print_r($array);
       //$xml->next(); <- тупил тут
    }
}
```

на выходе получаю это:

```
Array (
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [internal-id] => 1400455
        )

    [type] => аренда
    [property-type] => коммерческая
    [category] => коммерческая
)
Array (
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [internal-id] => 1400456
        )
    // вот тут должны быть данные по узлу 1400456
)
```

Xml файл полностью валидный, с ни точно проблем не может быть. Проблема только в том, что я делаю что-то не так. Доку по XMLReader перечитал, возможно что-то пропускаю...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в `$xml->next()`